# Getting the 5th character from the end of a string

Tags: php, string, substring

Is there a faster way to get the 5th character (***R***) from the end of the string **1234R1_t1**?

I get it using this code:

```
$string = "1234R1_t1";
$new_string = substr(substr($string, -5),0,1);
echo $new_string;
```

Comment: `$str[strlen($string)-5];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`substr("1234R1_t1", -5, 1)` should do it.

Comment: You should vote to close question when there is exact duplicate question instead of posting answer.